# I want to display my lightning page as record page in salesforce1 app

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, salesforce1-app

I have a lightning page and it's working fine in Desktop as record page.
But i want to display same page in salesforce1 app when we choose a deal from Opportunity list.

Help me if this possible

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_add_cmp_salesforce1.htm

Comment: @d_k That's not my ans. I am not looking for custom tab i am looking to add a action that redirect to my lightning page from a default salesforce1  Opportunity tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there are limitations around adding Lightning record pages to Salesforce1. If you need to access a custom Lightning page from an Opportunity it would be best to create it as a Lightning Component Action which would be available in the Action Bar when viewing a record.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_using_lex_s1_config_action.htm